# For each category, how to find the value of a column corresponding to the minimum of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, min

I have a table that looks like this; it is the stacked version of a crosstab, so each combination of item and period is unique:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| item | period | value |
+------+--------+-------+
| x    |      1 |     6 |
| x    |      2 |     4 |
| x    |      3 |     5 |
| y    |      1 |     9 |
| y    |      2 |    10 |
| y    |      3 |   100 |
+------+--------+-------+
```

**For each item, I need to find the period with the lowest value**, so the desired result is:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| item | period | value |
+------+--------+-------+
| x    |      2 |     4 |
| y    |      1 |     9 |
+------+--------+-------+
```

I have looked into pandas.DataFrame.idxmin() but it doesn't seem to be what I need.
**I have found a way with groupby, min and merge but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution?**

I have found many similar questions related to R and SQL (my solution is in fact "SQLish", but not to Python

My solution is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['item'] = np.repeat(['x','y'],3)
df['period'] = np.tile( [1,2,3] ,2 )
df['value'] = [6,4,5,9,10,100]


min_value = df[['item','value']].groupby('item').min().reset_index(drop = False)

periods_with_min_value = pd.merge(min_value, df, how ='inner', on=['item','value'])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df.loc[df.groupby("item")["value"].idxmin()]
Out[12]: 
  item  period  value
1    x       2      4
3    y       1      9
```

Tested on pandas 1.1.3, python 3.7, debian 10 64-bit. No warning was emitted.

N.B. This solution won't work if there were repeated or corrupted index values. This could be resolved by `.reset_index(drop=True)` in advance.

Comment: I have tried it on my actual data and I get an error message about missing labels, which I do not understand - is idxmin returning missing labels?

KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64'). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"

Comment: Your index might be corrupted. Perhaps `.reset_index(drop=True)` and try again? I am using pandas 1.1.3 and no warning was emitted. This operation seems quite regular to me.

Comment: It turns out I had some rows with value = nan, that's what was causing the issue